# Correlate terms with a scalar value

Tags: spark-mllib

There's a list of tuples `Double -> Set[String]`.

| score | tems |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | [foo, bar, baz] |
| 0.9 | [foo, baz] |
| 0.3 | [foo, bar] |
| 0.1 | [foo, bar] |
| 0.8 | [foo] |

- The size of the dataset is `10k rows`
- number of terms in every row is around `100`
- total number of unique terms is around `20k`
- **score** varies from `0.0 to 1.0`
- distribution of **score** values is pretty skewed towards 1.0

I'm trying to find an approach to correlate terms with the lower score values. In the example above term `bar` would show strong correlation to low scores. And `foo` isn't selective at all. Also 20k of terms seems to slowing down the computation. Is there a nice way to reduce the set of terms by removing those which aren't selective? I think that it's a good idea to remove very rare terms too.

So far I've mapped terms to hashes, mapped hashes to numbers, mapped score to buckets of Integers `{ 0, 10, 20, 30 .. 100}`. Now I have `List[(Int, Set[Int])]`. I've tried to apply TF-IDF and Chi squared test, but it looks like I'm lost due to lack of experience and time to find the right solution.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the association `0.1 -> [foo, bar, baz]` a shorthand notation for *three* associations `0.1 -> foo`, `0.1 -> bar`, and `0.1 -> baz`?  If yes, can you please explain why you not simply base your criterion on quantiles (e.g. upper quartile) of the score distribution for a term?

Comment: @cdalitz Ah, right. Thanks a lot for the hint!